# How can I insert an BlueOcean link in the body of an e-mail in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile and I want to send out a links to the Blue Ocean webpage in the body of the notification e-mail should a failure occurs. This will let other developers know that something went wrong and so that they know where to begin to look. This is what I have at the moment in my Jenkinsfile:

```
always {
  echo "Test run completed"

  script {
    EMAIL_TEXT = "THE BUILD HAPPENED"
    email_recipients = emailextrecipients(["foo@bar.com"])
    emailext(body: "${EMAIL_TEXT}",
      mimeType: 'text/html',
      subject: "Build Notification: ${JOB_NAME}-Build# ${BUILD_NUMBER} ${currentBuild.result}",
      from: 'hello@bar.com',
      to: "${email_recipients}".trim()
    )
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is what I need to add/change to make this work. And I can only go through the Jenkinsfile, this is due to admin restraints that I'm working with right now.

Blue Ocean is a Jenkins plugin that is being used: https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean/

I've tried looking through documentation, but have not found something that will shed light on my ignorance of this specific edge-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the URL for the logs in blue ocean are in this form:

```
http://your-jenkins-server/blue/organizations/jenkins/${JOB_NAME}/detail/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/pipeline
```

You can create the URL using the format above and send this in your email. If you additionally only want this email to file when the build fails, add it under a `failure` block.

Comment: This is the approach that I went with. Just adding environment variables where needed helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @gp443 Just be carful as this url may change in future releases, this is why it is better to user the environment variables populated by the plugin.

Comment: I looked through env-vars.html and frustratingly couldn't find such an environment variable. I double-checked to make sure that I'm not losing my marbles, but I didn't see anything. I'll pick my admin's brain for suggestions, he has full control over Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to generated the URL by yourself it is available for every job as an environment variable called `JOB_DISPLAY_URL` or if you want the link to the individual build (usually more useful) it is available via the parameter `RUN_DISPLAY_URL`.

In general Jenkins enables to define a **preferred user interface** in the system, when you install the BlueOcean plugin it is automatically defined as the preferred interface, you can then navigate to `<YOUR_JENKINS_URL>/env-vars.html/` to see all available system environment variables and you will see something like the following:

> **JOB_DISPLAY_URL**
>      URL that will redirect to a Job in a preferred user interface
> **RUN_DISPLAY_URL**
>      URL that will redirect to a Build in a preferred user interface
> **RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL**
>      URL that will redirect to Artifacts of a Build in a preferred user interface
> **RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL**
>      URL that will redirect to Changelog of a Build in a preferred user interface
> **RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL**
>      URL that will redirect to Test Results of a Build in a preferred user     interface

As stated above, if the BlueOcaen plugin is installed all these environment variables will point to the relevant sections in the blue ocean interface.

Comment: The env-var.html tip has helped me to solve a different problem. Thank you!

Comment: But what if it is NOT the default interface and an email should include links to both UIs?

Comment: Well, there are no other interfaces available currently, but there is another option to extract it via groovy system code.